# How to read XML attribute values using JXPathContext if reference is missing

Tags: java, jxpath

Given following XML, we are  using JXPathContext to create Java object out of it.

```
<fb1:Activity fb2:metadata="Activity1">
</fb1:Activity>
<fb21:ActivityMetadata fb2:id="Activity1">
    <fb1:Response>XXXX</fb1:Response> 
</fb1:ActivityMetadata>
```

reading the value -

```
String responseCode = context.getValue("metadata[1]/Response/value");
```

This is working as expected. Now lets say for instance, the reference from Activity to ActivityMetadata is missing. What can we do to read the response value in such case? It is guaranteed that there can only be one ActivityMetadata element at max in the XML.

Incomplete XML - need to parse this

```
<fb1:Activity fb2:metadata="">
</fb1:Activity>
<fb21:ActivityMetadata>
    <fb1:Response>XXXX</fb1:Response> 
</fb1:ActivityMetadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

The path you're giving us doesn't match the document you're showing us.

Ignoring that for a moment: 
XML doesn't constrain the tree at all; that's done by the XML Schema (if there is one) and/or the applications which process that kind of document. Only the folks who defined this particular kind of document, or the schema, or the code can tell you whether there are any guarantees about only one ActivityMetadata being present or what it means if there's more than one.

XML is pure syntax. Meaning is someone else's problem.